# Insert A Href Inside Echo Statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

> I'm currently working in an online reservation system. My problem is i
>   want to add a a href="" tag in the delete statement below, i'm trying
>   some code but it doesn't work.

**my code**

```
<?
echo'<tr class="">
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="name">'.$fetch['name'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="lname">'.$fetch['lname'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="ticketid">'.$fetch['ticketid'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="vehicle">'.$fetch['vehicle'].'</td>
<td>'.$fetch['pickuptime'].'</td>
<td><div align="right"><a href="\myfelicia\uploads/'.$fetch['billing_image'].'">'.$fetch['billing_image'].'</a></div></td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="status">'.$fetch['status'].'</td>

<td class="delete" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="delete">'.$del.'</td></a>
</tr>';
}
?>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: want to add href to where? in the element which has delete class?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that, this what you wanted

```
<?php
echo'<tr class="">
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="name">'.$fetch['name'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="lname">'.$fetch['lname'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="ticketid">'.$fetch['ticketid'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="vehicle">'.$fetch['vehicle'].'</td>
<td>'.$fetch['pickuptime'].'</td>
<td><div align="right"><a href="\myfelicia\uploads/'.$fetch['billing_image'].'">'.$fetch['billing_image'].'</a></div></td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="status">'.$fetch['status'].'</td>

<td class="delete" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="delete"><a href="#your_link_goes_here">DELETE</a></td>
</tr>';
?>
```